# el evento (change) en un formulario select no me realiza la consulta sino hasta la segunda vez que selecciono uno de sus elementos de la lista

Tags: angular

estoy aprendiendo Angular y estoy usando Boostrap
tengo un formulario select que lo lleno con el siguiente código, pero solo me realiza la consulta cuando selecciono por segunda vez cualquier elemento de la lista, no se a que se deba:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
       <label>Board</label>
    <select name="BoardID" #BoardID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="formData.BoardID" class="form-control"
       (change)="updateTolerance($event.target)" [class.is-invalid]="!isValid && formData.BoardID==null">
       <option value=null>-Select-</option>
       <option *ngFor="let board of boardList" value="{{board.BoardID}}">{{board.BoardID}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

A continuación la función para llamar los datos:

```
ongetDevelopmentList(){
    if (this.formData.StyleID !=0 && this.formData.FluteID !=0 && this.formData.BoardID !='')
      this.developmentService.getDevelopmentList(+this.formData.StyleID, this.formData.FluteID, 
    +this.formData.ClosureID).subscribe((developments : Development[]) => {
      this.developmentList = developments}, error => console.log(error));
};
```

el codigo en el proveedor de servicios, para este casoo get:

```
getDevelopmentList(styleID: number, fluteID: number, closureID: number): Observable<Development[]>{
    return this.http.get<Development[]>(environment.apiURL + '/Development/' + styleID + '/' + fluteID 
    +'/' + closureID);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que te pasa utiliza esto:

```
(ngModelChange)="updateTolerance($event.target)"
```

con el ya te debe lanzar el evento.